# GCC compiler manual

Tags: command-line, gcc, manpage

I'm trying to call the manual of the GCC compiler from the terminal, but I seem to be unable to, I only get error messages when I type:

```
gcc man
```

Surely I'm doing it wrong, but I can't find any topics around.

Comment: your command tries to compile a file named 'man'.  You should be using `man gcc` to see the reference-manual page for gcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get information beside `man gcc` (you have to change the order of your cmd) 
by using

```
info gcc
```

To get a short command description type

```
gcc --help
```

For a full manual install the gcc documentation by

```
gccv=$(gcc --version | awk '/gcc /{print $NF}' | cut -c 1)
sudo apt install gcc-$gccv-doc
```

and then type

```
xdg-open /usr/share/doc/gcc-$gccv-doc/gcc.html
```

to read the gcc manual in your browser.

Comment: Ah! I see! So the syntax is always man first! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**To view manual use this commands order:**

```
man gcc
```